Understanding 〝打つ〟の動作の〝う〟の頭をとらえて押し込む
So this is uh a follow-up to this question. I have difficulty understanding this sentence:

相手が打つときの、「〝打つ〟の動作の〝う〟の頭をとらえて押し込む」というような、言葉にすると奇妙としか言いようのない呼吸がある

If I am not mistaken, 呼吸 is modified by 相手が打つときの, 「〝打つ〟の動作の〝う〟の頭をとらえて押し込む」というような, and 言葉にすると奇妙としか言いようのない. I get what the first and third modifiers mean but I have trouble with the second one. What the quoted text means? I suspect it is something among the lines of "recognize the opponent's strike and immediately strike them with your sword"? I am uncertain what 頭 and 押し込む might mean.

Loosely related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/100264/5010


呼吸 is modified by 相手が打つときの, 「〝打つ〟の動作の〝う〟の頭をとらえて押し込む」というような, and 言葉にすると奇妙としか言いようのない

Correct.  "There's certain 呼吸 that's like [ 相手が打つときの, 「〝打つ〟の動作の〝う〟の頭をとらえて押し込む」というような], which sounds peculiar when put into words.

〝打つ〟の動作の〝う〟の頭

This is where @naruto mentions the relationship to an existing question about "見鬼のけの字".
頭 here means the head, the front, the tip (as in the head of a nail). 「う」 is the first letter of 打{う}つ, and the phrase figuratively expresses the very first portion (頭) of the initial movement （う） of the strike （打つ の動作）:

The head/tip/front of the (first letter) "s" of the motion of the strike

It seems that if you react to 〝打つ〟の動作の〝う〟, that's too late. You have to know the beginning of the beginning of the motion, probably even before the strike is started.
The rest: you have to recognise the "う"の頭. 押し込む here can probably be understood as "push forward" or "plunge". The actual action involved in 押し込む is not explicitly specified. It might mean the movement of the sword, your body or your spirit, but I am not sure. Probably some experience in Kendo, fencing or some other combat sport (which I don't have) might help feel the meaning.
